# systemctl edit problem "Failed to connect to bus"

Tags: systemd

When I attempt to create a new systemd unit (on Ubuntu 16.04)

```
$ sudo systemctl edit --user --full --force wagoOpenhabBridge.service
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
```

Apart from this problem my systemd is running fine.
After some internet research, I checked these things:

- I'm not using docker, Ubuntu is running directly on Intel NUC x64 hardware
- systemd is running with PID=1
- XDG variables in env are

  ```
  XDGSESSIONID=1790   
  XDGDATADIRS=/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop     
  XDGRUNTIMEDIR=/run/user/1000
  ```

Any ideas what is going wrong?  What other things can I check?

Comment: Why are you using `sudo` to edit a user unit?

Answer (score 16):

I just came across a similar problem, it was caused by trying to run a service as a user I was not logged in with (this user has login disable, and I was using `su` and `sg` to fake it).

### Why `sudo` ?

You have probably added `sudo` because the command was not working, you can safely remove it. A **user** systemd service is a regular file owned by the regular user.

### Fixing `Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory`

I found the solution on [stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/245866/130000), the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` seems to be missing from your environment.

Your command can be run as this:

```
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/$UID"
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/bus"
systemctl edit --user --full --force wagoOpenhabBridge.service
```

### Running the command before login

If you want the service to be started before the user login, don't forget to run:

```
sudo loginctl enable-linger USERNAME
```

Answer (score 4):

Solution is install `dbus-user-session` package (`sudo apt install dbus-user-session`), reboot and login again.

Answer (score 3):

There's another situation in which this happens, namely with a user that is "not properly logged in"... This can happen even if you have no `sudo` before your command (which shouldn't be there, see other answers).

Check first your `$UID` and then check if the directory `/run/user/$UID` actually exists. This might not be the case when for example logging in on a remote machine through one user and then switching to another user (that happen to have no admin rights) by e.g. `sudo su some-user`.

The `systemd` system uses `polkit` for authentication. To be sure that you're logging in as a given user with everything properly set, you can use a tool, `machinectl`, that can be installed with:

```
sudo apt install systemd-container
```

Now login using the password of one of your accounts to get a shell for "some-user" (replace with the proper user name):

```
machinectl shell some-user@
```

Now you will see that the directory `/run/user/$UID` exists, that you can find the XDG environment variables in your shell, and that you can run the `systemctl --user` commands.

Comment: Wow, this worked! Do you know why **regular** login (although in multi-seat setup) could have failed to create `/run/user/1001` directory, dbus, etc.. ?

Comment: I am no expert at this, but one reason I found is that you need to set `UsePAM yes` in /etc/ssh/sshd_config. Some tutorials recommend disabling it when using public key only login.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `dbus` package installed?

I've noticed a similar issue when running `systemctl show $UNIT` as a user, with a connection attempted on `/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket` which only exists if `dbus-daemon --system` is running, which itself needs the `dbus` package to be installed.

You can investigate further by using `strace` to check what syscalls are performed, and determine which exact issues this *Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory* is about. Even if not trying to access the system bus, it's likely to be D-Bus related.

Your `systemd` package might have `dbus` in `Recommends` (that's the case in Debian 9 at least); checking those is usually a good idea when something doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error (`Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory`) when running the following command on Ubuntu 20.04:

`systemctl --user mask tracker-store.service tracker-miner-fs.service tracker-miner-rss.service tracker-extract.service tracker-miner-apps.service tracker-writeback.service`

The problem was because of the alias:

`alias systemctl='sudo systemctl'`

It substituted the `systemctl` with `sudo systemctl` and sudo caused the error.