# How to debug: Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory (systemctl --user status)?

Tags: server, systemd, dbus

I am trying to run `systemctl --user status` from a user account in order to not run services from root.

The way I do it is as follows:

1. `loginctl enable-linger $USER`
2. `export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/$UID"`

Then when I run `systemctl --user status` I get the following error: `Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory`

What I tried to debug this.

1. Setting the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`  env variable by: `export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/bus"` This did not fix it. ([source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1007055/systemctl-edit-problem-failed-to-connect-to-bus))
2. Rebooting the server after every change.
3. Reinstalling dbus by `sudo apt reinstall dbus-user-session`

I also noticed that the `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` directory does not exist e.g. `sudo ls -l /run/user/1001`

I am not sure what else to try or how to learn more about this problem in order for me to able to address it in a more informed manner.

Any info that can help me debug and understand this is very welcome.

P.S. I am running Ubuntu 20.04.5 and the problem likely happened after a `sudo apt-get upgrade` I ran. Before that it was working well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, however rebooting helped. You should also know that you will need to edit the .bashrc for the user. Check out my wiki page for instructions

https://dw.exitstatus0.com/doku.php?id=wiki:systemd_user_service#troubleshooting